# Create instance of static library for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I'm using a library that contains a lot of static methods in my program. I wanted to run some code in parallel (multithreaded) that calls some of these static methods. This causes a problem because there's only one instance of the static class that is shared between the threads. This causes crashes. Is it possible to create an instance of this library for each thread? I cannot change any code within the library as it's closed source.

The run method in my thread:

```
public void run(){
    for (String formula : input) {
        try {
            Formula converted = (Formula) logic.createExpression(formula);
            System.out.println(converted);
            Formula  cnf = ClassicalLogic.Utilities.conjunctiveForm(converted, true);
            if (cnf.toString().equals("true")) {
                convertedFormulae.add(ClassicalLogic.Utilities.conjunctiveForm(converted));
            } else {
                convertedFormulae.add(cnf);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    converter.threadReady(convertedFormulae);
}
```

The problem is the line:

```
Formula  cnf = ClassicalLogic.Utilities.conjunctiveForm(converted, true);
```

What I'm actually asking for is how I can create a seperate instance of ClassicalLogic.Utilties for each thread?

Comment: I don't see a problem; what is the actual error? Static methods by themselves are not a problem, but shared data in static fields is.

Comment: Yes the problem is the fact that this static method changes the values of some static fields in the Utilities class causing NullPointerExceptions to be thrown in some threads because data is changed by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: One way to deal with it is to create your own proxy class for ClassicalLogic.Utilties with all methods synchronized and use your class instead of ClassicalLogic.Utilties. However, it will not help if you need data integrity through out the execution within a single thread.
Alternatively, you can use different class loader per thread and load ClassicalLogic.Utilities in each thread explicitly by the thread's class loader. Then you will technically have different versions of the same class and they will not share static members.

Comment: @Peter L thank you! How exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different class loader for each thread. Something along these lines should help.

Try this inside `run` method (assume that the jar file is classicallogic.jar:

```
URLClassLoader clsLoader = 
     URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:///<path_to_classicallogic.jar>")});
Class cls = clsLoader.loadClass("classicallogic.ClassicalLogic.Utilities");
Method cF1 = cls.getMethod("conjunctiveForm", Formula.class);
Method cF2 = cls.getMethod("conjunctiveForm", Formula.class, boolean.class);
```

Then instead of calling

`ClassicalLogic.Utilities.conjunctiveForm(converted, true)`

or

`ClassicalLogic.Utilities.conjunctiveForm(converted)`

you do this

`cF2.invoke(null, converted, true);`

or

`cF1.invoke(null, converted);`